# How to capture value change event of Datagrid's cell in WPF?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm using `Datagrid` to show some MySQL tables.Naturally,I expect that changes in datagrid should be reflected in MySQL table.I've write a command to handle the `Cell value changed event`,however,the command did not hit:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Table_DataGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyServerWrapViewModel.TableFromMySql,
                  Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TargetUpdated">
            <cmd:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding updateCell}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

I think that I was listening to the wrong event,because my `updateCell` did not hit...How do you catch `cell value changed event` of datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution.

First add the related `ViewModel` as the `DataGrid's DataContext`.otherwise the compiler won't know where to find the binding command.

```
DataContext="{Binding MyServerWrapViewModel,Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Then change `TargetUpdated` to `CurrentCellChanged`.

Comment: This looks strange in WPF Ways. You will have to set your ViewModel as the DataContext of the DataGrid-surrounding View. Then the DataGrid automatically gets the same Context because it inherits down...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to attach an event? Usually you will create a DataBinding for your Column against some Property of an object in an ObservableCollection. Changes in a Grid's cell will be directly pushed into the setter of the Property you bound to. From there you can do whatever pleases you, like writing to the db or set a modified flag.

Comment: You can not directly bind to a MySQL table.To read a MySQL table,you have to put it in a `DataTable` by `MySqlDataAdapter`.To reflect the change back to MySQL table,you have to call the `Update` method of `MySqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Well that's the point. You should really think about creating objects reflecting your tables design and bind to these. Providing something like a ViewModel with ICommand Implementations but pushing Values into a Database is no MVVM style (at least you called your class ...ViewModel).

Comment: Even in additon it will be much harder to implement a good validdation, User, Feedback, etc...